# How do you programatically remove (not disable) a button from TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I can disable the table button using this:

```
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('divId_table').setDisabled(true)
```

but what I'm interested in is actually hiding it. Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

First, you have to use the advanced theme.

Then, add this option in the TinyMCE init code.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    theme_advanced_disable : "bold, justifyleft, justifyright"
});
```

I hope this might help someone.

[source](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_disable)

[list of elements' name here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with TinyMCE myself, but since you appear to have javascript access to the element itself, all you need to do is set it's display property to "none".

```
document.getElementById("theButton").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

incase ur trying to hide a specific button, use the following code.

$('.mce_cut').hide() //hides cut button

lookup other button titles using firebug in case u wish to hide something specific.

Incase you are looking to hide specific editor's button, modifiy the jquery selector to select correct sibling/descendent.

alternately, try this ..
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.controls.ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_5005db96_e035_4197_a958_75f008b35061_ctl00_tbKeywords_cut.remove()

Note that ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_5005db96_e035_4197_a958_75f008b35061_ctl00_tbKeywords is my asp.net control's id. Don't bother about this if ur not using Asp.net serverside textbox control. In case you are.. <% theTextBoxID.ClientID %> gets u that.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following (using jQuery; a non-jQuery approch is easily built):

```
var elem = $(ed.id+'_'+'divId_table')
elem.addClass('mceButtonDisabled');
elem.removeClass('mceButtonEnabled');
```